# Unity cannot read string variable from PlayerController

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `public string startPoint` set in my PlayerController. I am accessing this string from another script PortalController and I am setting and reading it which works for the most part.

My problem is:

I read the `Debug.Log(thePlayer.startPoint);` when the first start scene loads from the PortalController
I can set the `startPoint` and load the second scene and I can confirm from the Unity panel that it is indeed set for the PlayerController in the second scene.
However I cannot read the `Debug.Log(thePlayer.startPoint);` from the second scene. It come out blank and has a length of 0. No errors.

PlayerController

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    float speed = 2f;
    Vector2 targetPos;

    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    private Animator myAnim;

    private static bool playerExists;

    public string startPoint;

    private void Start()
    {
        startPoint = "startValue";

        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        if(!playerExists){
            playerExists = true;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
        } else {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        targetPos = transform.position;

    }
```

PortalController

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class PortalController : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private string sceneToLoad;

    public string portalName;
    public string spawnPortal;

    private PlayerController thePlayer;
    private CameraController theCamera;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        thePlayer = FindObjectOfType <PlayerController>();

        //works in the first scene but not in the second
        Debug.Log(thePlayer.startPoint);

        if (thePlayer.startPoint == portalName)
        {
            thePlayer.transform.position = transform.position;
            //Debug.Log(thePlayer.startPoint);
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.name == "Player"){
            thePlayer.startPoint = spawnPortal;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneToLoad);
        }
    }
}
```

The Player object does not get destroyed between scenes and a new portal gameObject get created. It seems like that when the new portal gameObject with the PortalController get created in scene two it cannot access the string `startPoint` in the PlayerController the PortalController in scene in could have.

If I load scene two directly `Debug.Log(thePlayer.startPoint);` works fine. It only stops switching

Comment: I have doubt, that you `Start()` method inside `PlayerController ` not firing in second scene.

Comment: Yes the `Start()` method does not fire in the second scene because the player is not destroyed. I set a new value for the `startPoint` before I load the new scene in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` which does work. However when the new PortalController in the second scene loads it cannot read the value even though it is there

Comment: Did this line `thePlayer = FindObjectOfType <PlayerController>();` work or is `thePlayet` null?

Comment: Yes `thePlayer = FindObjectOfType <PlayerController>();` works. I tried `Debug.Log(thePlayer.name);` which works fine

Comment: And what is the value of `portalName`? What output would you expect exactly?

Comment: Sorry I mean `spawnPortal`

Comment: A portal gameObject is a 2d block collider which goes over doors in the scenes. If you enter the back boor of the house when the inside house scenes loads I want the player to spawn at the back door inside. `spawnPortal` moves the player to the back or front door when switching scenes

Comment: I got that but what is the value of `public string spawnPortal`? This is what you asign to the players `startPoint` so I just want to be sure it is not simply empty.

Comment: Definitely not empty. I have set it in scene one both in the Unity panel and then with code to be sure and it logs correctly. But in scene two it still shows in the panel but `Debug.log()` blank in code

Comment: Certainly if there is no error on -> private PlayerController thePlayer;
This means the reference is there and so must be the variables inside it.

If you get this reference in first scene and load the other make sure this gameobject is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code with PlayerController and PortalController in 1st scene and Only PortalController in 2nd scene and the output is what you are expecting, no errors and getting startPoint value perfectly.

But make sure on start of 2nd scene player isn't colliding with portalController or else it will call triggerEnter another time and set value of SpawnPortal of 2nd scene's PortalController which can be blank and that's why you are getting this issue.

You can check that by debug in triggerEnter..

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("OnTriggerEnter " + collision.gameObject.name);
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        thePlayer.startPoint = spawnPortal;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneToLoad);
    }
}
```